# Arrange Array in C# Issue

Tags: c#, arrays

I've an array sequence 20,40,60,10,30,50. I want to sort this sequence into the following order 60,40,50,20,30,10 in C#.

Any Help? Thanks in advance☺

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: People need to note that the desired output is NOT in descending order. Its a test question which he is not giving all the requirements for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my Quick Sort Algorithm sort the arrays in both Ascending and Descending order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803531/how-can-i-make-my-quick-sort-algorithm-sort-the-arrays-in-both-ascending-and-des)

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple if you have an Array

`int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 0, 2, 10 };
    arr.OrderBy(a => a);
     arr.Reverse();`

in case of list

`List<int> abc = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 0, 2, 10 };
   abc.Sort();
   abc.Reverse();`

Answer (score 0):

Just use **OrderByDescending** of LINQ:

```
var list = new[] {20, 40, 60, 10, 30, 50};
var newList = list.OrderByDescending(x => x);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", newList)); //60,50,40,30,20,10
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
int[] array = new int[] { 20, 40, 60, 10, 30, 50 };
    Array.Sort<int>(array,
                    new Comparison<int>((element1, element2) => element1.CompareTo(element2)));
```

to reverse sort

```
element2.CompareTo(element1)
```

Comment: can you explain in briefly

Comment: MSDN Link :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AmitMishra How is it working? the output is entirely different from what you have posted: "**into the following order 60,40,50,20,30,10**"

Comment: Sir can you provide me a answer using an example?

Comment: @AmitMishra can you provide exact rules for the sorting of the array?